# Location class that keeps track of x and y

Tags: java, location

Im doing an excercise for school where I need to write a program that keeps track of the x, y position of say a figure within a grid.

- up() moves figure up.
- down() moves figure down.
- left() moves figure left.
- right() moves figure right.

This is what I have so far and the problem is that i just get 0,0 when running the program.

Im not that good at programming, so sorry if its really bad.

```
package øving_1;

public class Location {


    private int xAkse;
    private int yAkse;


    public Location(){
        xAkse = 0;
        yAkse = 0;      
    }

    public void right(int i){
        xAkse++;
    }

    private void left(int i){
        xAkse--;

    }

    private void up(int i){
        yAkse--;

    }

    private void down(int i){
        yAkse++;
    }
    public int getPosition(){
        return xAkse;
    }
    public int getPosition2(){
        return yAkse;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Location location = new Location();
        location.right(0);
        location.left(0);
        location.up(0);
        location.down(0);

        System.out.print("Posisjonen til x, y er: ");
        System.out.print(location.getPosition() + ", " + location.getPosition2());


    }

}
```

Comment: You've gone left once, right once, up once and down once.  That puts you back at your starting position (0,0).  Why would you expect a different location?

Comment: It works as it should. You started at 0,0 then moved right, left, up, down. Since all of your moves cancel each other out, you're back at 0,0. BTW, your move commands (up,down, left, right) don't need a parameter in their method definitions & calls

Comment: What @azurefrog said.  Also, though, why do your `left()`, `right()`, `up()`, and `down()` methods each accept an argument that they do not use?

Answer (score 0):

The *i* arguments are not used, but the rest of the code is right.

It's precisely what you would expect: if you move one step right, then one step left, then one step up, then one step down, you're again in the spot where you were at the beginning.

It's geometry, baby.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. The thing is that I wanted it to move to a new position, and not cancel each other out. Should have explained better in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting 0,0 with your main method you current have.

You start at location `0,0`. Then you call `right()`, which moves you right 1 unit. You are now at `1,0`. You then call `left()` which moves you left 1 unit. Now you are back at `0,0`. Then you call `up()`, so you move to position `0,1`. Finally you call `down()`, which puts you back at position `0,0`.

Try doing something like:

```
Location location = new Location();
location.right(0);
location.right(0);
location.right(0);
location.down(0);

System.out.print("Posisjonen til x, y er: ");
System.out.print(location.getPosition() + ", " + location.getPosition2());
```

And you should get position `3,-1`.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**: you get `(0, 0)` because:

1. `Location location = new Location()` -> (0, 0);
2. `location.right(0)` -> `xAkse++` -> (**1**, 0);
3. `location.left(0)` -> `xAkse--` -> (**0**, 0);
4. `location.up(0)` -> `yAkse--` -> (0, **-1**);
5. `location.down(0)` -> `yAkse++` -> (0, **0**);

and it's right.

If you want to **improove** your code, you can add a constructor which allows you to create a specific location:

```
public Location(int xAkse, int yAkse){
    this.xAkse = xAkse;
    this.yAkse = yAkse;      
}
```

If you want to move up, down, left and right of a certain quantity, use the `i` params which isn't currently used, for example:

```
public void up(int i) {
    yAkse -= i;
}

public void right(int i){
    xAkse += i;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
Location location = new Location(10, 10);
location.right(3);
location.up(5);
```

Location will be `(13, 5)`.

Another readability hint: change the `getPosition()` and `getPosition2()` names in `getXAkse()` and `getYAkse()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a custom class containing a [Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html).

That would look like this:

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class CustomPoint {
    //VARIABLE
    private Point point = null;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public CustomPoint(int x, int y) {
        this.point = new Point(x, y);
    }

    //METHODS
    public void goUp() {
        this.point.y++;
    }

    public void goDown() {
        this.point.y--;
    }

    public void goRight() {
        this.point.x++;
    }

    public void goLeft() {
        this.point.x--;
    }

    public void printCurrentLocation() {
        System.out.println("Current Location: (" + point.x + "/" + point.y + ")");
    }

    //GETTER AND SETTER
    public Point getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    public void setPoint(Point point) {
        this.point = point;
    }

}
```

I made an example how you could keep track on your point:

```
public class RunMe {



public static void main(String[] args) {

     CustomPoint cp = new CustomPoint(0, 0);

            cp.printCurrentLocation();
            cp.goDown();
            cp.printCurrentLocation();
            cp.goUp();
            cp.printCurrentLocation();
            cp.goLeft();
            cp.printCurrentLocation();
            cp.goRight();
            cp.printCurrentLocation();

        }
    }
```

What generates following output:

```
Current Location: (0/0)
Current Location: (0/-1)
Current Location: (0/0)
Current Location: (-1/0)
Current Location: (0/0)
```

> BIG ADVANTAGE

If you need to calculate the distance between 2 Points, there is already a solution!

```
CustomPoint a = new CustomPoint(0, 0);
CustomPoint b = new CustomPoint(3, 2);

System.out.println(a.getPoint().distance(b.getPoint()));
```

Prints the following line on the console:

```
3.605551275463989
```